# Circle - circle collision response (balls stuck overlapping)

Tags: javascript, collision, geometry, p5.js

I'm trying to build something like this in JavaScript using p5.js:

[image: Circle - circle collision]

I'm able to detect collision between two circles and I'm trying to calculate the new speeds using these (two-dimensional elastic collision) formulas from Wikipedia:
[image: Elastic collision formulas]
With these angles for theta and phi:
[image: Collision angles]

The problem seems to be that when I have calculated the new speeds, the balls are already collided / overlapping and they are getting stuck. What I think I should do is calculate a new circle position based on the distance that the circles are overlapping. Unfortunately I'm not sure how to do this. I also think that the way I'm calculating is overly complex and inefficient. 
This is what my collision handling code looks like:

```
  // takes ball object as input, sets speedvector to new x,y speed
  collision(other) {
    var newSpeed = createVector();
    var phi = Math.atan((this.pos.y - other.pos.y) / this.pos.x - other.pos.x);
    var theta1 = this.speed.heading();
    var theta2 = other.speed.heading();

    newSpeed.x = (this.speed.mag() * Math.cos(theta1 - phi) * (this.mass - other.mass) + 2 * other.mass * other.speed.mag() * Math.cos(theta2 - phi)) / (this.mass + other.mass) * Math.cos(phi) - this.speed.mag() * Math.sin(theta1 - phi) * Math.sin(phi);
    newSpeed.y = (this.speed.mag() * Math.cos(theta1 - phi) * (this.mass - other.mass) + 2 * other.mass * other.speed.mag() * Math.cos(theta2 - phi)) / (this.mass + other.mass) * Math.sin(phi) + this.speed.mag() * Math.sin(theta1 - phi) * Math.cos(phi);

    this.speed.x = newSpeed.x;
    this.speed.y = newSpeed.y;
  }
```

The complete code example:

```js
var balls = [];
var numOfBalls = 5;
var maxSpeed = 2;


function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < numOfBalls; i++) {
    var ball = new Ball(30);
    balls.push(ball);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    balls[i].move();
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    balls[i].show();
  }
}

class Ball {
  constructor(radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.pos = this.pickLocation();
    this.speed = createVector(random(-maxSpeed, maxSpeed), random(-maxSpeed, maxSpeed));
    this.mass = 1;
  }
  
  pickLocation() {
    //spawn within canvas
    var xOption = random(this.radius, width - this.radius);
    var yOption = random(this.radius, height - this.radius);
    
    // check whether spawning on this location doesn't overlap other circles
    for(var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
      // don't check for current circle
      if(balls[i] != this) {
        // get distance to other circle
        var d = dist(xOption, yOption, balls[i].pos.x, balls[i].pos.y);
        // check whether overlapping
        if (d <= this.radius + balls[i].radius) {
          // generate new location and rerun check
          console.log("overlapping another circle, trying new location");
          var xOption = random(this.radius, width - this.radius);
          var yOption = random(this.radius, height - this.radius);
          i = -1;
        }
      }
    }
    return(createVector(xOption, yOption));
  }
  
  move() {
    for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
      if(balls[i] != this) {
        var d = dist(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, balls[i].pos.x, balls[i].pos.y);
        if(d < this.radius + balls[i].radius) {
          this.collision(balls[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    
    if(this.pos.x - this.radius < 0 || this.pos.x + this.radius > width) {
      this.speed.x *= -1;
    }
    if(this.pos.y - this.radius < 0 || this.pos.y + this.radius > height) {
      this.speed.y *= -1;
    }
    
    this.pos.x += this.speed.x;
    this.pos.y += this.speed.y;
  }
  
  // takes ball object as input, sets speedvector to new x,y speed
  collision(other) {
    var newSpeed = createVector();
    var phi = Math.atan((this.pos.y - other.pos.y) / this.pos.x - other.pos.x);
    var theta1 = this.speed.heading();
    var theta2 = other.speed.heading();
    
    newSpeed.x = (this.speed.mag() * Math.cos(theta1 - phi) * (this.mass - other.mass) + 2 * other.mass * other.speed.mag() * Math.cos(theta2 - phi)) / (this.mass + other.mass) * Math.cos(phi) - this.speed.mag() * Math.sin(theta1 - phi) * Math.sin(phi);
    newSpeed.y = (this.speed.mag() * Math.cos(theta1 - phi) * (this.mass - other.mass) + 2 * other.mass * other.speed.mag() * Math.cos(theta2 - phi)) / (this.mass + other.mass) * Math.sin(phi) + this.speed.mag() * Math.sin(theta1 - phi) * Math.cos(phi);
    
    this.speed.x = newSpeed.x;
    this.speed.y = newSpeed.y;
  }
  
  show() {
    fill(200, 100);
    noStroke();
    ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.radius * 2);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Also: how are you handling the case when more than two circles collide?

Comment: Maybe you could give each ball an id and store the id of the last ball hit, ignore collisions with that ball (clear it out on wall bounce?)

Comment: @KevinWorkman I added the example. This should be imported in an HTML file combined with p5.js (I'm using this link: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.9/p5.min.js). I haven't thought about how to handle more than two circles colliding. Would be glad if I could get this to work with two circles to start with.

Comment: Have you tried debugging your program? Which line of code is behaving differently from what you expected?

Comment: @KevinWorkman I have tried. I'm for example sure that my objects speed vector is being updated after collision. However, I've never had any education regarding programming, if you could recommend a tutorial that would be very helpful. I would expect my objects to change direction after they collide, but I think that since they are overlapping (by a small amount), they keep colliding, thus sticking together and changing direction continuously. I think the collision happens between frames and I should calculate at which point collision takes place and update the objects position accordingly.

Comment: @Muxor Cool, sounds like you've got a plan. What happened when you tried that?

Comment: @Muxor https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp310/s17/lectures/lec15/exact_coll.html

Answer (score 1):

I made this code. I completely changed the collision function but it's working great!
also, constrained the position so it won't get stuck on the walls.

I made the exact thing a few months ago so you can look at it
[here](https://editor.p5js.org/tony.j.h.zhang/sketches/STBrZuomCf)

I also divided the canvas into grids so it is a lot more efficient than looping through every ball.

mine can do about 4000 balls before it lags

they way the collision function works is like the newton's cradle. the two objects change speeds(ball A which is moving hits stationary ball B and now ball A doesn't move and ball B moves at the same speed ball A was)

```js
var balls = [];
var numOfBalls = 5;
var maxSpeed = 2;


function setup() {
  createCanvas(500, 500);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < numOfBalls; i++) {
    var ball = new Ball(30);
    balls.push(ball);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    balls[i].move();
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    balls[i].show();
  }
}

class Ball {
  constructor(radius) {
    this.radius = radius;
    this.pos = this.pickLocation();
    this.speed = createVector(random(-maxSpeed, maxSpeed), random(-maxSpeed, maxSpeed));
    this.mass = 1;
  }
  
  pickLocation() {
    //spawn within canvas
    var xOption = random(this.radius, width - this.radius);
    var yOption = random(this.radius, height - this.radius);
    
    // check whether spawning on this location doesn't overlap other circles
    for(var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
      // don't check for current circle
      if(balls[i] != this) {
        // get distance to other circle
        var d = dist(xOption, yOption, balls[i].pos.x, balls[i].pos.y);
        // check whether overlapping
        if (d <= this.radius + balls[i].radius) {
          // generate new location and rerun check
          console.log("overlapping another circle, trying new location");
          xOption = random(this.radius, width - this.radius);
          yOption = random(this.radius, height - this.radius);
          i = -1;
        }
      }
    }
    return(createVector(xOption, yOption));
  }
  
  move() {
    for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
      if(balls[i] != this) {
        var d = dist(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, balls[i].pos.x, balls[i].pos.y);
        if(d < this.radius + balls[i].radius) {
          this.collision(balls[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    
    if(this.pos.x - this.radius < 0 || this.pos.x + this.radius > width) {
      this.speed.x *= -1;

    }
    if(this.pos.y - this.radius < 0 || this.pos.y + this.radius > height) {
      this.speed.y *= -1;

    }
    
    this.pos.x += this.speed.x;
    this.pos.y += this.speed.y;
    this.pos.x = constrain(this.pos.x,0,500)
    this.pos.y = constrain(this.pos.y,0,500)


  }

  // takes ball object as input, sets speedvector to new x,y speed
  collision(other) {
    this.v1 = 0;
    this.v2 = 0;
    this.direction = p5.Vector.sub(other.pos, this.pos)
    this.dist = this.direction.mag()
    this.direction.normalize();
    //this is 60 because that is the radius you give them times two
    this.correction = 60-this.dist;
    this.pos.sub(p5.Vector.mult(this.direction,this.correction/2))
    other.pos.add(p5.Vector.mult(this.direction,this.correction/2))
    this.v1 = this.direction.dot(this.speed)
    this.v2 = this.direction.dot(other.speed)
    this.direction.mult(this.v1-this.v2)
    this.speed.sub(p5.Vector.mult(this.direction,1));
    other.speed.add(p5.Vector.mult(this.direction,1))

    
  }
  
  show() {
    fill(200, 100);
    noStroke();
    ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.radius * 2);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I just realized this is two years ago but I hope other people can use this or something